# Would a posterior distribution with a flat prior look identical to the likelihood?

Tags: bayesian, likelihood, prior, posterior

Graphically, let us assume that we have a flat prior for a normal distribution (a horizontal line at y=1 over all real numbers).

Then, we have a likelihood function that resembles a normal distribution.

Would the posterior distribution essentially look identical to the likelihood? If so, that means that the likelihood function (i.e., data) is completely responsible for the resulting posterior distribution, correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes and no. If your prior distribution is as you described, an improper flat prior, the posterior will take the shape of your likelihood; however, the likelihood still needs to be normalized. Conclusion: the posterior will look like the normalized likelihood.

It is worth noting that flat priors are not invariant under transformation. That is you could transform your parameter of interest, and suddenly your flat prior would be informative as opposed to being flat. This implies your posterior is no longer solely dictated by your likelihood.

See [Jeffreys Prior](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jeffreys_prior) for an objective prior that is invariant under reparameterization.